# Customer Attribute require error magento 2

Tags: customer-attribute, magento-2.1.2

I am adding customer attribute in magento 2

```
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'test', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Test',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 90,
            'position' => 90,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'test')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();
```

add in register.phtml

```
<div class="field test">
            <label for="test" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Test') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getTest()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Test') ?>" class="input-text">
            </div>
        </div>
```

and now when i add values in form for register it gives me an error

> "Test" is a required value

What to do? i can't understand

Answer (score 0):

Change **required=>true** to **required=>false**

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'test', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Test',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,//Change here
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 90,
        'position' => 90,
        'system' => 0,
    ]);
```

Comment: i want this attribute as require field

Comment: when `"Test" is a required value` error message comes?

Comment: I want attribute as require field and when i am submit form and it redirect to registration page and show this error

Comment: have you entered any text in that field or without its you an give error?

Comment: of course! I enter text in that field

Comment: @Newbie you got solution if yes then please let me know